# how to get strings stored in a database contain few give words arranged in decreasing order of words found in the string

Tags: mysql, sql

Give few words . How to write an SQL query to search if the strings stored in the database contains those words and arrange them in decreasing order of number of words found in a string..

Comment: Show what you have tried and what road blocks you got. Try searching on google first.

Answer (score 0):

If these few words are well known (and not dynamic), and if performance is not that critical, then try the following:

```
select c,
    if (c like '%sam%', 1, 0)
  + if (c like '%tom%', 1, 0)
  + if (c like '%suse%', 1, 0)
  + if (c like '%jack%', 1, 0)
  + if (c like '%lemon%', 1, 0) as weight
from someTable
order by weight
```

Code is tested under MySQL 5.6 with the following schema:

```
create table someTable(
  c varchar(50)
);

insert into someTable (c) values ("sam tom suse jack lemon");
insert into someTable (c) values ("sam suse some other words");
```

Comment: Thank u for Ur answer....as I see here the order of the words matters coz it's searching for sam then Tom then suse and so on ...if Sam comes after Tom will it work?